# Using Python for adding column in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have csv file (inputFile) like below:

```
Temperature,2,3
Temperature,5,6
Pressure,11,14,45
Pressure,13,23,16
Humidity,21,24,25
Humidity,27,28,26
```

and I want to write it into another file(outputFile), but in the following format:

```
Temperature,2,3,Pressure,11,14,45,Humidity,21,24,25
Temperature,5,6,Pressure,13,23,16,Humidity,27,28,26
```

I have tried following Python code:

```js
with open('inputFile.csv','r') as csvinput:
 with open('outputFile.csv','w') as csvoutput:
  writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, delimiter= ',')
  writer = csv.writer(csvoutput)
  for row in csv.reader(csvinput):
   if (row[0] == "Pressure" or row[0] == "Humidity"):
    type =row[0]
    Value = row[1])
         writer.writerow(row + [np.asarray(type)] + [np.asarray(Value)])
```

Which is giving the output in the follwoing format:

```
Temperature,2,3,Humidity,27

Temperature,5,6,Humidity,27

Temperature,8,9,Humidity,27

Pressure,11,14,45,Pressure,11

Pressure,13,23,16,Pressure,13

Humidity,21,24,25,Humidity,21

Humidity,27,28,26,Humidity,27
```

Please help!

Comment: Is the input format always the same? i.e. is it safe to assume equal rows for temperature, pressure and humidity? All in order?

Comment: yes the number of rows of temperature, humidity, pressure will always  same like here it is 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binary mode is missing.

To increase readability I suggest to separate read, change data and write because you have to read the whole input file before writing.

Example (without error handling):

```
  import csv
  f = open('inputFile.csv','rb')
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  data = {}
  keys = set ()
  for row in reader : 
    key = row [0]
    data.setdefault (key, []).append (row) 
  f.close ()
  odata = []
  for (t, p, h) in zip (data ["Temperature"], data ["Pressure"], data   ["Humidity"]) :
    odata.append (t + p + h)
  g = open('outputFile.csv','wb')
  writer = csv.writer (g)
  writer.writerows (odata)
  g.close ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file as `wb` rather than `w`.

This may only apply if you are running on Windows. It's an issue with line seperators in file handles.

Comment: Ok, that's removes the problem of new line, but i have issues also in writing the output file, as it is not same as i want..

Comment: One problem solved:) It looks like in the `if row == Pressure or` bit you are only checking for two things - have you tried checking for all three?

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open('inputFile.csv','r') as csvinput:
    with open('outputFile.csv','w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, delimiter=',')
        types = ('temperature', 'pressure', 'humidity')
        data = {key: [] for key in types}
        for row in csv.reader(csvinput):
            data[row[0].lower()].append(row[1:])
        for entry_no in range(len(data['temperature'])):
            row = []
            for key in types:
                row.extend([key.title()]+data[key][entry_no])
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could do anything with the way the inputFile.csv is written it would make life for you much easier. Either way here is an pandas alternative that does solve your problem.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('inputfile.csv', names=['type', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3'])
df = df.T

a = range(0, len(df.columns))
rows = [a[::2], a[1::2]]

dic = {}
for i in range(0, 2):
    dic[i] = [df[df.columns[j]].tolist() for j in rows[i]]
    dic[i] = [j for x in dic[i] for j in x]
    dic[i] = [x for x in dic[i] if str(x) != 'nan']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dic)
df1.T.to_csv('outputFile.csv', index=False, header=False)
```